# wpdb->insert creates duplicate rows

Tags: actions

**mypage.php**

```
 $create_args = array(
            "user_id" => get_current_user_id(),
             "description" => "Your order #".$order_id." has been successful"
         );
        do_action('ttm11_create_in_notification_table', $create_args);
```

**actions.php**

```
if(!function_exists('ttm11_create_in_notification_table')){
    function ttm11_create_in_notification_table($args){
       $args['created_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
       $args['created_by'] = get_current_user_id();
        global $wpdb;
        $table = $wpdb->prefix.'ttm11_notification';

        $insert = $wpdb->insert($table, $args);
    }
}




add_action('ttm11_create_in_notification_table', 'ttm11_create_in_notification_table',10,2);
```

I do not have any duplication of the function.

The same function inserts only one row, if I make an ajax call.

The same is code inserts only once in my localhost but when I move the codes to the server, it inserts thrice.

I have also confirmed by putting `var_dump("I am called")` inside the function and is executed only once.

Please let me know the possibilities of this happening.

Comment: How is `do_action( 'ttm11...table', $create_args);` triggered? What's the code around it?

Comment: I am using siteorigin page builder and there is a function called as get_template_variables, it triggers by default.

Comment: The code is incomplete. Please provide the code around the `do_action` call.

Comment: And how is the actions.php file included? Are you sure it's included only once?

Comment: The issue was with Yoast plugin. After disabling Yoast plugin, the code works fine. Since it is out of my scope, i did not go much into it. Thanks to all the supporters

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem here. The reason was that when loading a page in the frontend, WordPress actually was doing **two** requests:

- One to load the page
- A second one in the background after the page was loaded using `admin-ajax.php`

The solution was to make sure, out function was only executed during the "normal" page-load and not the AJAX request:

```
function my_callback() {
   if (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX) return;
   // do normal stuff here
}
```